# "views" directory missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Hey guys am trying to learn sails.js, I have followed some tutorials where the sails.js application has "views" directory (by default) but my setup doesnot have one.

- So I *created a directory* named it "**views**" inside project directory and then,
- I created an **index.ejs** file with `<h1>Hello World</h1>` as content.
- Configured the route `'/': {view: 'static/index'},`

Then I tried it in my chrome with `localhost:1337` and nothing showed up in the browser, but in the terminal I got a chunk of error out of which I found it saying **no such file or directory, open 'c:\project\views\layout.ejs'**.

What is it that Iam missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected there will be an app-wide layout file (named as what's missing).

Create or copy that file and things should be working again.

Comment: yea i copied the file from C:\mySailsproject\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-generate-views\templates\layout.ejs to Views and its working